# How to turn off the ANSI escape sequence of Bash?

Tags: bash, terminal, escape-characters

I am running Jest, and the output would go like: print a line (for a test), and then erase it, and print another line.

However, if I use a loop to do the tests (using `expect`), there is no way to see a full list of tests. (the selectors, etc).

I also tried:

```
jest foo.js &> result.txt
```

but it appears jest can determine it is not a terminal type and therefore will not out those lines any more.

I also looked into the options of `jest` and didn't find anything that will work.

So one hack I think can be: what if the terminal does not have these ANSI escape sequence support (to erase a line, etc), so then, the output has to be one line after another.

Is there a way to do it?  The environment is Terminal on macOS Sonoma.

Answer (score 0):

Just tell that you have a terminal which do not support such features, e.g. putting

```
TERM=vanilla jest foo.js
```

or set the environment variable at beginning of your script (remember to `export` it: the environment variable need to be used by all child processes).  See https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.ti.html for a description of various terminals.

A good program will check terminals, and put escape code only if terminal support it. Unfortunately (as you see many answer in this stackoverflow site), many programmers are lazy and send escape code anyway, without querying terminal capabilities.

Note: there are also some utilities which remove ansi sequences, but I do not remember the names.

Comment: This seems to be spam more than an answer.

Comment: @Seamus: it is the official website and upstream of xterm, terminfo, ncurses, etc. Not related to me, no tracking, not advertisement (and all people have already installed the software he maintains) -- But I'm more worried that you stalked my answers just to find one with a link, in order to verbatim copy a comment I made to you. Not healthy. Not healthy. Take a short break.

Comment: Why, whatever made you think such a thing?